# LinkedHashSet modifying sets

Tags: java, linkedhashset

I have the following code:

```
  private static class Node {
    public LinkedHashSet<String> s = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    public Node(String s) {
        this.s.add(s);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedHashSet<Node> set1 = new LinkedHashSet<Node>();
    set1.add(new Node("foo"));

    LinkedHashSet<Node> set2 = new LinkedHashSet<Node>(set1);

    LinkedHashSet<String> modifyingSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    modifyingSet.add("modifying foo");

    for(Node n : set2) {
        n.s = new LinkedHashSet<String>(modifyingSet);
        break;
    }

    if (compare(set1, set2)) {
        System.out.println("Equal");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not Equal");
    }

    return;
 }
private static boolean compare(LinkedHashSet<Node> h1, LinkedHashSet<Node> h2) {
      Iterator<Node> h1i = h1.iterator();
      Iterator<Node> h2i = h2.iterator();
      while (h1i.hasNext()) {
            Node n1 = h1i.next();
            Node n2 = h2i.next();
            if (n1.s.size() != n2.s.size()) {
                return false;
            } else {
                Iterator<String> it1 = n1.s.iterator();
                Iterator<String> it2 = n2.s.iterator();
                while (it1.hasNext()) {
                    String t1 = it1.next();
                    String t2 = it2.next();
                    if(!t1.equals(t2)) {
                        return false;
                    }   
                }           
            }
      }
      return true;
}
```

When I modified set2, set1 gets modified with the String "test" and "bogus" as well. So when I compare both sets, they are always equal (`compare()` compares if the string in each sets are equal)

**My question is:**

From my understanding, Java passes by value, but it seems that it was passed by referenced. Could anyone help me out figure it out why? And how can I, copy the set to a temporary set, and then modify the set but not modify the first set?

I feel like I am missing something quite simple here.

Answer (score 6):

There's a lot of problems and misconceptions here, so here's a list.

a) You *cannot* modify elements of a `Set` and expect it to still work.  The [Javadoc for `Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) is more specific:

> Note: Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set elements. The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set. A special case of this prohibition is that it is not permissible for a set to contain itself as an element.

Always assume "unspecified behavior" translates to "it explodes in your face," or to "it will work only on Tuesdays when it's raining in Albequerque, so it might work half the time and might explode the other half."

b) You must override `hashCode()` and `equals(Object)` to use an object in a `HashSet` or `LinkedHashSet`, if you don't want them to be compared by `==`, which it looks like you probably shouldn't in this application.

c) Java passes *references by value*, which is different from pass-by-value *and* from pass-by-reference.  In particular, modifying an object will affect all references to the same object, but changing the reference to refer to a different object will have no effect on the other references.

```
Set<Foo> set1 = new LinkedHashSet<Foo>();
Set<Foo> set2 = set1;
Set<Foo> set3 = set1;
set1.add(new Foo());
// set1, set2, and set3 each refer to the same Set, which now contains one Foo
set3 = new LinkedHashSet<Foo>();
// set1 and set2 still refer to the Set with one Foo;
// set3 now refers to a new empty Set
```

d) To copy a `LinkedHashSet`, just do `new LinkedHashSet<Foo>(setToCopy)`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommened you use `HashSet`. Second, these structures are immutable. You have to call a specific method to modify an element in the set.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `compare` method is buggy. Can you post its implementation?

The `for` loop doesn't modify `set2`. So, `set2` should remain empty while `set1` has some elements. So, I expect that the `compare` method always returns `false`. However, I doubt that you want `set2` to remain empty, but, that's another issue.

**UPDATE**:

The `compare` method throws `java.util.NoSuchElementException` (See http://ideone.com/nv1wmN). There are several misunderstandings that lead to these bugs. The first step is to realize that `set2` is empty when `compare` is invoked.

Comment: I modified the code to when set2 is initialized, it copies set1. I agree the compare() is badly written, but when I am in debug mode, I can see that set1 and set2, have the "modifying foo" string.